# Viewport doesn't scale to center

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries, viewport

I am using this on the site

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=200px, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
```

In my CSS file I have this for repositioning some elements

```html
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #wb_element_instance3{display: none}
    #wb_element_instance11 {left: 280px}
    #wb_element_instance12 {left: 570px}
    #wb_element_instance13 {left: 655px}
    #wb_element_instance14 {left: 705px}
}
```

And now my problem. When I access my website with my phone the stuff in "@media" works fine but the viewport scales a bit offset that to the center of the site.

So, is there a way to center it somehow?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please add some of your html,  to help illustrate the issue

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me! Well, I am using a viewport and media to relocate some text fields and remove an image for the mobile version, but the viewport scales a bit to the left offset the center. Tried to reset the width of the page in media which works on desktop but not on mobile? :(

Comment: add some of the html , then we can make a runnable example. It's harder to solve an issue that one can't reproduce. You can edit your question to add to it.

Comment: Most android mobiles are 480 (old) to about 640 (newer) px wide. iOS older ones are 320px so your absolute positioning that you have coded will  move your code, probably off screen.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your very fast reply! Please send me an email here and I will send you php site and the approrpiate CSS jo.stacktest@web.de

Comment: pls remove your email from the site. This site is here so that everyone can share answers. Your question can be edited to add css. View my answer below, it will probably solve your problem. Remember to remove the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You've given very little information to help solve the issue, but some general pointers apply.
1) Absolute positioning (using top/left etc.) is not a good idea, especially if you're coding with a view to centering on devices of multiple sizes.

2) You could cater better for different size devices by adding other media queries. 
 e.g. `@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:640px){
       }` or

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:480px){/*your css here*/}
```

etc.

Centering can usually done by using the `margin` property or text-align. Bear in mind that some css can affect other css properties. If you are centering an image, assign it a width (in percentage) and then  you could use `margin: 0 auto` or margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;

Example of (text-align) centering:

```css
.wb_example{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="wb_example">Hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: p.s this site is very useful for testing http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: @Tester2 why are you using content=200px in your viewport? If you removed the absolute positioning and added media queries as advised above, and adjusted your meta to  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5"> , (note the device-width) , your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for all of that inconvience :( Why did I started that page with a website builder one year ago, very complicated in some cases when it comes to input own code... Maybe all the code will help you now

Comment: @Tester2 I'm actually on holiday.. and yes auto builders are rubbish in general.. much easier if you do your own ... hosting isn't expensive..

Comment: Yup, oh okay no problem, I will to maybe rewrite a part, as it really s**** almost everytime when I have to change something of the layout. Again thank you very much for your effort :)

Comment: Hi again, I've rewritten everything and now everything works as it should. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: @Tester2 you're welcome. Could you accept the answer please ?  Thanks.